# Remove spacing between footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I am trying to remove all spacing between separate footnotes in a `memoir` document. Not spacing between lines within a footnote, but spacing between distinct footnotes. I have been told to set the length of `\footnotesep` to zero, but this does not seem to work. Neither does it work to adjust `\parskip`.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0mm} % To my understanding, this should remove the spacing, but it does not seem to.

\begin{document}

This is\footnote{\lipsum[1]} sample\footnote{\lipsum[1]} text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}.

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following document (attached as a picture). I want to remove the spacing between footnotes highlighted in red.

[image: Here, to remove the spaces marked in red.]

Comment: It *is* working. This is a side effect of `\lipsum`. Use the starred version `\lipsum*` to see it.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. A silly mistake on my part; thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: It's not silly at all. To be precise it's a side effect of how `\lipsum` and `\footnote` are defined.

Comment: Note taken. I still have much to learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, as pointed out by user campa, is that this is «a side effect of `\lipsum`»; and indeed by using «the starred version `\lipsum*`» all unwanted spacing disappears.

Therefore:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0mm} % Working as intended.

\begin{document}

This is\footnote{\lipsum*[1]} sample\footnote{\lipsum*[1]} text\footnote{\lipsum*[1]}.

\end{document}
```

Credits once again to user campa, because sure enough, the spacing disappears:

[image: No more spacing.]